# How can i remove a blank space at the top of a table in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop, scene2d

I have been trying to remove a blank space at the beginning of a libgdx table (it is a table inside a table inside a scrollPane).

The only thing I have found on the matter is to remove the line

```
setFillParent(true);
```

And I dont have that anywhere in my code

here is my adding to the table

```
colorTable.add(colorTitleBar).width(350).height(120);
colorTable.row();
colorTable.add(colorChoices).width(350).height(120);
colorTable.pack();
```

Here is a screen shot of the problem it is in the colors table

[image: Blank padding on colors table]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You want the colorTable to be at the top?

Comment: @Arctic45 i want the box that contains the label Colors and the skin, hair, and eyes table to be at the top of the scrollPane that they are added too

Comment: @Arctic45 the part i want to be higher is the colorTitleBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// set padTop if you want to leave some space at the top
colorTable.add(colorTitleBar).width(350).height(120).expandY().top().padTop(...);
colorTable.row();
```

And take a look at [LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#alignment) for `Table`